# PBR Graph option not showing up in Unity

Tags: unity, unity-shader-graph

I downloaded the URP render pipeline into an existing project of mine (created using the 3D template) to try out shader graphs. All of the guides and tutorials I'm following use an option called the "PBR Graph". However, I can not find that option in Unity. Did they change the name of the graph? How can I get access to it?

When I open up a new project using the URP template, I have the option to choose the PBR graph, but not in my original project, so do I have to create the project with the URP template to begin with?

The version I am using is 2020.2.3.
[image: Settings]

[image: Options]

Comment: That's the "Lit Shader Graph"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@10.2/manual/Upgrade-Guide-10-0-x.html), Unity removed that option in the 10.0.x version of shader graphs, and added cross-platform master nodes to the master stack as long as the shaders are compatible with both the Universal Render Pipeline (URP) and the High Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP). Unity did not remove the option entirely however, and people can still use them, according to what Unity has said in the website above.

> In URP, you can now find all PBR Master Node settings in the URP Lit
> Target. The Unlit Master Node settings are in the URP Unlit Target.
> These settings are the same, and the final shader should appear the
> same as before the upgrade.